# zimbra Received headers

Tags: email, header, zimbra

I installed Zimbra 9 Open Source build by Zextras on ubuntu 18. Everything works fine, except for the extra headers. 
I try to remove received headers from sended mails (all headers like this: **Received: from... by ...**).
At first, I have like this:

```
Delivered-To: me@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a5d:488c:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id ...;
        Tue, 4 Jan 2022 08:53:22 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ...
X-Received: by 2002:a17:906:229b:: with SMTP id ...;
        Tue, 04 Jan 2022 08:53:22 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1641315202; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=...
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=thread-topic:thread-index:mime-version:subject:message-id:to:from
         :date:dkim-signature:dkim-filter;
        bh=...
        b=...
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@domain.org header.s=F6EBFE12-68E2-11EC-8CB9-115052E52692 header.b=qO7Nn1lY;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of admin@domain.org designates domain-ip as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=admin@domain.org;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=domain.org
Return-Path: <admin@domain.org>
Received: from mx1.domain.org (mx1.domain.org. [domain-ip])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id ...
        for <me@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_3 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 bits=256/256);
        Tue, 04 Jan 2022 08:53:22 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of admin@domain.org designates domain-ip as permitted sender) client-ip=domain-ip;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@domain.org header.s=F6EBFE12-68E2-11EC-8CB9-115052E52692 header.b=qO7Nn1lY;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of admin@domain.org designates domain-ip as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=admin@domain.org;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=domain.org
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by mx1.domain.org (Postfix) with ESMTP id DBDA31807F1 for <me@gmail.com>; Tue, 4 Jan 2022 16:53:21 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from mx1.domain.org ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (mx1.domain.org [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10032) with ESMTP id XkOWdVTrcHNd for <me@gmail.com>; Tue, 4 Jan 2022 16:53:21 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by mx1.domain.org (Postfix) with ESMTP id 84ECF1807F2 for <me@gmail.com>; Tue, 4 Jan 2022 16:53:21 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Filter: OpenDKIM Filter v2.10.3 mx1.domain.org 84ECF1807F2
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=domain.org; s=...; t=...; bh=... h=Date:From:To:Message-ID:MIME-Version; b=...
X-Virus-Scanned: amavisd-new at domain.org
Received: from mx1.domain.org ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (mx1.domain.org [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10026) with ESMTP id jlS3dyZaaFn8 for <me@gmail.com>; Tue, 4 Jan 2022 16:53:21 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from mx1.domain.org (mx1.domain.org [mx1 local ip]) by mx1.domain.org (Postfix) with ESMTP id 68EE11807EE for <me@gmail.com>; Tue, 4 Jan 2022 16:53:21 +0000 (UTC)
Date: Tue, 4 Jan 2022 16:53:21 +0000 (UTC)
From: admin@domain.org
To: me <me@gmail.com>
Message-ID: <1641315201373.JavaMail.zimbra@domain.org>
Subject: 555
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=...
Thread-Index: ...
Thread-Topic: 555
```

In this headers I have **7** "Received" blocks
After this, I do in console:

```
> zmprov mcf zimbraMtaBlockedExtensionWarnRecipient FALSE
> zmprov mcf zimbraMtaHeaderChecks 'pcre:/opt/zimbra/conf/postfix_header_checks  pcre:/opt/zimbra/conf/custom_header_checks'
```

and put into **custom_header_checks** this lines:

```
/X-Virus-Scanned/     IGNORE
/^X-Originating-IP:/     IGNORE
/^X-Mailer:/     IGNORE
/^Mime-Version:/     IGNORE
/^User-Agent:/     IGNORE
/^X-Sanitizer:/     IGNORE
/^X-Spam-Status:/     IGNORE
/^X-Spam-Level:/     IGNORE
/^X-MimeOLE:/     IGNORE
/^X-MSMail-Priority:/     IGNORE
/Message-Id:\s+<(.*?).JavaMail.zimbra@domain.org>/ REPLACE Message-Id: <$1@domain.org>
/^Received: (.*?)/ IGNORE
/^Received:/ IGNORE
```

After these actions I get this headers:

```
Delivered-To: me@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a5d:488c:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id ...;
        Tue, 4 Jan 2022 09:27:44 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ...
X-Received: by 2002:aa7:cd71:: with SMTP id ca17mr9922635edb.19.1641317264625;
        Tue, 04 Jan 2022 09:27:44 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=...; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=...
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=thread-topic:thread-index:subject:message-id:to:from:dkim-signature
         :dkim-filter:date;
        bh=...
        b=...
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@domain.org header.s=F6EBFE12-68E2-11EC-8CB9-115052E52692 header.b=aTzRC9NO;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of admin@domain.org designates domain-ip as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=admin@domain.org;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=domain.org
Return-Path: <admin@domain.org>
Received: from mx1.domain.org (mx1.domain.org. [domain-ip])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id ...
        for <me@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_3 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 bits=256/256);
        Tue, 04 Jan 2022 09:27:44 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of admin@domain.org designates domain-ip as permitted sender) client-ip=domain-ip;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@domain.org header.s=F6EBFE12-68E2-11EC-8CB9-115052E52692 header.b=aTzRC9NO;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of admin@domain.org designates domain-ip as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=admin@domain.org;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=domain.org
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by mx1.domain.org (Postfix) with ESMTP id 339761807F7 for <me@gmail.com>; Tue, 4 Jan 2022 17:27:44 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from mx1.domain.org ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (mx1.domain.org [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10032) with ESMTP id IDUM9YOcCGqX for <me@gmail.com>; Tue, 4 Jan 2022 17:27:44 +0000 (UTC)
Date: Tue, 4 Jan 2022 17:27:43 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Filter: OpenDKIM Filter v2.10.3 mx1.domain.org F0B571807F8
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=domain.org; s=...; t=...; bh=...; h=Date:From:To:Message-Id; b=...
From: admin@domain.org
To: me <me@gmail.com>
Message-Id: <1641317263779@domain.org>
Subject: 666
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=...
Thread-Index: ...
Thread-Topic: 666
```

There are **4** blocks "Received" left.
How I can remove at least the last two?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue:
In console:

```
zmlocalconfig -e postfix_header_checks="pcre:/opt/zimbra/conf/postfix_header_checks, pcre:/opt/zimbra/conf/custom_header_checks"
```

After in file **/opt/zimbra/common/conf/master.cf.in** from string:

```
-o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_address_mappings
```

remove **no_header_body_checks**